# Redux Toolkit - assign entire array to state

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

How can I assign an entire array to my intialState object using RTK?

Doing `state = payload` or `state = [...state, ...payload]` doesn't update anything.

Example:

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'usersLikedPosts',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    getUsersLikedPosts: (state, { payload }) => {
      if (payload.length > 0) {
        state = payload
      }
    },
  },
})
```

payload looks like this:

```
[
  0: {
    uid: '1',
    title: 'testpost'
  }
]
```

**update**

Doing this works but I don't know if this is a correct approach. Can anyone comment?

```
payload.forEach((item) => state.push(item))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`immer` can only observe modifications to the object that was initially passed into your function through the `state` argument. It is not possible to observe from outside the function if that variable was reassigned, as it only exists in the scope within the function.

You can, however, just `return` a new value instead of modifying the old one, if you like that better. (And in this case, it is probably a bit more performant than doing a bunch of `.push` calls)

So

```js
return [...state, ...payload]
```

should do what you want.

Comment: can you explain more plz

Comment: @AmineDa. give https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers a read - This specific quesion is regarding to the chapter "Resetting and Replacing State" but I'd recommend to read the whole thing.